# Can you use Groovy code to create and modify data in a Grails migration?

Tags: grails, migration, grails-2.0, seeding

The goal - in a single deploy/restart, I want to create a new table and populate some records, as there will be code changes that expect this data to be there.

The ideal - to write a migration that accomplishes this. Imagine that I've created my `Foo` class, generated a migration that creates the `foo` table with `grails dbm-gorm-diff ....`, and run the migration with `grails dbm-update`. I now have both my domain class and my database table. Cool.

Now I'll write a new migration that populates the table.

```
databaseChangeLog = {
    changeSet(author: "samslotsky", id: "PopulateFooTable") {
        grailsChange {
            change {
                new Foo(bar: 'baz').save()
                new Foo(bar: 'blitz').save()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'll add that to the changelog.groovy

```
include file: 'populate-foo-table.groovy'
```

After running `grails dbm-update` again, there are no records in my `foo` table. It's not a validation issue because I can create `Foo` objects just fine from application code. I'm not even sure how to tell whether or not my migration has been executed, since breakpoints don't seem to catch within migrations.

So I suppose there are two good questions to ask:

1. Besides looking for side effects (i.e. my db table being populated), how can I be sure that my migration has even executed?
2. How can I create new records from a migration? Can I use Groovy code, or am I stuck writing SQL?

I realize that I could create the table and domain class first, deploy it, create an import tool or admin interface to seed the data, and then modify the code to consume the data. I *really* don't want to go through all of that. I should be able to do this seamlessly, with a single deploy, like I would in Rails.

Thanks!

Comment: Create the records in Bootstrap?

Comment: @JamesKleeh: I don't think Bootstrap runs on production.

Comment: Bootstrap should run in production - I use it all the time to do exactly this.

Comment: @Samo Shouldn't [MigrationCallbacks](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/guide/4%20General%20Usage.html) be useful here if Liquibase is used. Grab datasource and add items in `afterMigrations` callback?

Comment: @Samo - Bootstrap runs in production

Comment: @JamesKleeh: I should have been more clear. Bootstrap runs in production if `bootstrap.init` is set to true in your production configuration. Ours is not.

Comment: @dmahapatro: wouldn't that callback run every time `dbm-update` is executed? I only want to do this once.

Comment: You can have a check like "If the specific row `exists` then do not `save` it again".... :)

Comment: @dmahapatro: that could work, but it's far from ideal. Should I conclude based on these comments that it's not possible to do this in a migration? If that's the case, does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Ideally, you would be doing this in a migration. The `callbacks` will only be called after migration completes which makes it atomic. Callbacks are useless without migration. On the other hand, I agree that you won't be able to enjoy the flavor of Groovy DSLs as you have mentioned in the question.

Comment: This really should work. Try adding `failOnError: true` to the save to see if you are getting an error. Also add a `flush: true` to the last save.

Comment: Based the advantages of GORM, we can use Domain Classes to do db migrations instead of executing SQL statements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heres an example of my actual migration than ran and worked:

```
changeSet(author: 'me', id: 'createCodeTrees') {
    grailsChange {
        change {
            new CodeTree(name: 'BAN8', enabled: true, defaultTree: true).save(failOnError: true)
            new CodeTree(name: 'BAN8OLD', enabled: true, defaultTree: false).save(failOnError: true)
            new CodeTree(name: 'BANPPRD', enabled: true, defaultTree: false).save(failOnError: true)
            new CodeTree(name: 'BANADVM', enabled: true, defaultTree: false).save(failOnError: true)
            new CodeTree(name: 'BANSTFA', enabled: true, defaultTree: false).save(failOnError: true)
            new CodeTree(name: 'BANHRPY', enabled: true, defaultTree: false).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - knowing that it works for someone else helps me choose a direction to pursue!

Comment: It's bad practice to use domain classes in a migration, because if the domain changes the code may break.

Answer (score 6):

To my knowledge, here are the answers to your questions:

Per the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/guide/5%20Groovy%20Changes.html), you can execute Groovy code and an instance of groovy.sql.SQL is injected for you to execute SQL statements. You would want to do something like the following:

```
 databaseChangeLog = {
        changeSet(author: "samslotsky", id: "PopulateFooTable") {
            grailsChange {
                change {
                    sql.execute("insert into foo (bar) values ('baz')")
                    sql.execute("insert into foo (bar) values ('blitz')")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can look in the DATABASECHANGELOG table to determine if specific changesets have been executed.  There's even a [controller](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/guide/8%20DbDoc%20Controller.html) available to view this via HTML.